# Агрегатные функции в mysql

Tags: mysql

Не нашел про агрегатные функции в MySQL.

Расскажите про них пожалуйста. Какие, для чего, почему.

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос не очень понятен... Агрегатные функции нужны для обработки сгруппированных данных... Что еще Вы хотели услышать? Просто так объяснять нет смысла. Если бы у Вас было конкретное задание, и вы спрашивали бы какую функцию корректнее использовать, тогда можно ответить... а так... По-конкретнее спршивайте, получите хороший ответ...

Answer (score 3):

`AVG([DISTINCT] expr)`  Возвращает среднее значение аргумента expr

`BIT_AND(expr)` Возвращает побитовое И для всех битов в expr

`BIT_OR(expr)`  Возвращает побитовое ИЛИ для всех битов в expr

`BIT_XOR(expr)` Возвращает исключающее побитовое ИЛИ для всех битов в expr

`COUNT(expr)` `COUNT(*)` `COUNT(DISTINCT expr1, expr2, . . .)`  Подсчитывает количество записей в expr

`GROUP_CONCAT(expr)`    Объединяет значения отдельных групп, полученных в результате применения конструкции GROUP BY, в одну строку

`MIN([DISTINCT] expr)`  Возвращает минимальное значение среди всех непустых значений выбранных строк в столбце expr

`MAX([DISTINCT] expr)`  Возвращает максимальное значение среди всех непустых значений выбранных строк в столбце expr

`STD(expr)` `STDDEV(expr)` `STDDEV_POP(expr)`   Возвращает стандартное среднеквадратичное отклонение значения в аргументе expr

`STDDEV_SAMP()` Возвращает выборочное среднеквадратичное отклонение expr

`SUM([DISTINCT] expr)`  Возвращает сумму величин в столбце expr

`VAR_POP(expr)` `VARIANCE(expr)`    Возвращает стандартное отклонение значения в столбце expr

`VAR_SAMP(expr)`    Возвращает выборочное отклонение значения в аргументе expr

[первая ссылка](http://sevidi.ru/php/phppage48.php)

Comment: ну это я и так нашел..думал что то со знанием дела скажет.Но все равно спасибо)

Comment: @Ilya, "со знанием дела" это как?